# System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Int32[] to a known managed provider native type.'

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller, ado.net

I am trying to insert a list of IDs, but I am receiving the above error. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
public void CreateGroupRestriction(UserData userData, string message2)
    {           
        do
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.CreateRestriction", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter paramRoleName = new SqlParameter();
                paramRoleName.ParameterName = "@RoleName";
                paramRoleName.Value = userData.RoleName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramRoleName);

                SqlParameter paramRestrictionEntityTypeCode = new SqlParameter();
                paramRestrictionEntityTypeCode.ParameterName = "@RestrictionEntityTypeCode";
                paramRestrictionEntityTypeCode.Value = "O";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramRestrictionEntityTypeCode);

                SqlParameter paramRestrictionEntityID = new SqlParameter();
                paramRestrictionEntityID.ParameterName = "@RestrictionEntityID";
                Converter<string, int> converter = new Converter<string, int>(StringToInt);
                paramRestrictionEntityID.Value = Array.ConvertAll(message2.Split(','), converter);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramRestrictionEntityID);                    

                SqlParameter paramExclude = new SqlParameter();
                paramExclude.ParameterName = "@Exclude";
                paramExclude.Value = "0";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramExclude);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        } while

            (message2 != "");
        
    }
```

Comment: The error is happening at this line:  paramRestrictionEntityID.Value = Array.ConvertAll(message2.Split(','), converter);

Comment: What it says is that you are trying to send an array of int to the parameter, and there is no mapping for that kind of type Int32[], what kind of parameter is @RestrictionEntityID?.

Comment: The parameter is just an Id (int). I am sending a list of IDs to this parameter, then using the "split" to get the substrings in an array to perform the multi-insert.

Comment: Can you show the error thrown so it can be easier to solve the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.